# How to manually generate the fingerprint of PuTTY's cached host keys?

Tags: putty

I'm currently working on a wrapper app for PuTTY and trying to find a way how to store the host keys inside my app, as I want it to be portable.

The basic idea: By using plink and prepending `echo y |` I would force to store the host key in the registry (\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys), read the key and then compute the fingerprint. Then I would store the fingerprint in my app's configuration and undo the changes in the registry. However, I don't know how to compute the fingerprint.

Example:

Connecting with plink gives me this host key fingerprint:

```
The server's ssh-ed25519 key fingerprint is:
ssh-ed25519 256 6e:3e:71:4f:b9:41:e6:09:cf:e1:b8:f4:bd:5a:9e:9b
...
Store key in cache? (y/n)
```

Choosing "y" will create this registry key:

```
ssh-ed25519@22:192.168.0.100    0x6e05d2e71d8c86744d27c19ffb96854576cc41c66334d04e93f491023ce42b53,0x1cc99868f5709847f5b0fc1af5d1582b58bed02bc44b73db150cbe0dc09c9c60
```

What to do with these 2 hex strings to get the fingerprint?

Comment: What the point of your "basic idea" in the first place? Do not try to bypass the host key verification!

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your comment. I don't want to bypass the host key verification. I want to store them somehow into the configuration file of my portable PuTTY wrapper app. Then I can start a PuTTY session with the "-hostkey" parameter. This way, if my app runs on another computer (where the hostkeys are not cached in registry), there will be no hostkey popup, because the hostkey is directly read from the configuration file of my app.

Comment: If all you want is to retrieve the host key fingerprint, why don't you just grab it from Plink console output?

Comment: Thanks, you're right. That's what I'll do.

Comment: But I mean manually, after you verify the fingerprint personally. Not automatically.